# Specify the type of a FrameworkElement in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, label, frameworkelement

My method accepts as argument any FrameworkElement. Then it checks if the FrameworkElement is a Label with the condition "if (MyFrameworkElement is Label)". If the condition is true, I want the program to change the FontSize property. But FontSize is not available for a FrameworkElement, I must indicate that it is a Label. How to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the `is` operator ([Microsoft documentation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) described in [this article](https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/152/c-sharp-7-is-operator-patterns-you-wont-need-as-as-often) like

```
if (myFrameworkElement is Label l)
{
    l.FontSize = 123;
}
```